# Batch convert multiple .GML files to postgis sql tables using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gdal, pgadmin, ogr2ogr

I have a folder with 150 .gml files I need to upload to my postgis/postgres database. After the first gml is uploaded, the rest will be appended to it to form a single table. However I don't know how to make ogr2ogr iterate through each file... currently I'm having to upload/append each cml induvidually.

My code to convert the first gml:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb user=admin password=password" -lco SCHEMA=test_schema "D:\path to folder\File1.gml" -progress -lco OVERWRITE=YES
```

and my code to append each subsequent gml to the first:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb user=admin password=password active_schema=test_schema" "D:\path to folder\File2.gml" -progress
```

This works fine but I don't want to do this another 148 times, changing File2 to File3 each time etc...

Answer (score 1):

Loosely copied from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/using-ogr2ogr-to-convert-all-shapefiles-in-directory), you need a loop:

```
for /R %f in (*.gml) do ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb user=admin password=password active_schema=test_schema" "%f" -progress
```